# How do you use a color palette for websites?

Tags: css, user-interface, web

How do you implement a color palette for a website?  For example given a color palette with five colors

```
#67CFE3 #A4D8D8 #DCE0C9 #EF842F #F66700
```

How do you assign the above colors to website components, that is what is the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

Given a [**selector**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) you can apply the color to your element in different ways:
as a background, as the color of the font, as the color of the border etc. see [**here**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/#color) an exhaustive list.

Looking at an [**example**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_color.asp) you see you can use color with hexadecimal, rgb, rgba, name etc.

Check out the global [**css syntax**](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp)

```
body { 
    color: red;
}

h1 {
    color: #00ff00;
}

p {
    color: rgb(0,0,255);
}
```